# How to implement a toggle button to set a Rails boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form with a checkbox on a boolean field.

I want to replace the checkbox with a toggle button, using Twitter Bootstrap.

Is there anything baked into Rails to provide this kind of functionality? Or will I need to write a script to update the checkbox value when the toggle button is clicked?

Thanks for any pointers. After a lot of searching, I've been unable to find anything that describes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time, the toggle Bootstrap buttons do not have the correct markup to work out of the box with forms ([source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1161)).

You can wrap around the controls to insert the correct values into your parameters map using hidden fields. If you're using AJAX requests, you can simply include them in your parameters there.

In the case of the single toggle, you could implement a function as simple as this to set the hidden value.

In your form:

```
<input name="toggled" value="false" />
```

Evaluated before submission:

```
function isToggled() {
   $('input[name="toggled"]').value($('#toggleButton').hasClass('active'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, the link you provided clarified things a lot. Until Bootstrap updates with the correct markup, I think I will stick with a checkbox. A toggle button would be more user friendly in my case, but it feels like shoe horning to make it fit at the moment. Thanks for your advice.